# Convert written date in c# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, converters

I get from an web service a date which is written like that :

```
"Tuesday, November 12, 2013 8:18:14 AM PST"
or
"Tuesday, November 12, 2013 10:36:03 AM PST"
or 
"Wednesday, November 13, 2013 5:15:58 AM PST"
...
```

This date is stored inside an Array and I would like to sort it. But It does not work properly. So I would like to store this written date in a DateTime or another format supported by the language. Than sort it again. I could be also easier to get only days and hours from a DateTime than using a strstr or something like that.

Is it possible (and how) to convert this written date into a DateTime please ?

PS: I already tried using `Convert.DateTime("Wednesday, November 13, 2013 5:15:58 AM PST")`. But It didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: _"But It didn't work"_ - did you try pasting the exception in the search box?

Comment: Is the web service guaranteed to *always* return Pacific Standard Time? And does it need to be converted for comparison with local DateTimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse it with format `"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:m:ss tt 'PST'"`

```
string str = "Wednesday, November 13, 2013 5:15:58 AM PST";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, 
                                "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:m:ss tt 'PST'", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have used single `d`, `h` and `m`, for day, hour and month since they will accept both single digit and double digits values.

Comment: `dt.Kind` is `Unspecified`. This might be an issue, if you try to convert it to a `Local` or `Utc` time.

Answer (score 1):

Becuase [`Convert.DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses current culture information.

> The value argument must contain the representation of a date and time
>   in one of the formats described in the `DateTimeFormatInfo` topic.

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with custom datetime format instead.

```
string s = "Wednesday, November 13, 2013 5:15:58 AM PST";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, 
                                  "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt 'PST'",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output will be;

```
11/13/2013 5:15:58 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/Onfnlm)</kbd>.

For more informations, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Do you have a "parse this datetime string for me" answer template? ;-)

Comment: @CodeCaster You sir, made my day `:)`. I wish I had one like a template. But seriously, `DateTime` and specially _parsing_ `DateTime` is one of the most powerful side of mine in C#. I wish I knew the subjects _generics_, _LINQ_, _Reflection_, _Regex_ as I knew as `DateTime` and parsing stuff `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If the date will always end with a 3 letter timezone abbreviation the following will work:

```
string str = "Wednesday, November 13, 2013 5:15:58 AM PST";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 4));
```